# Jquery $(this).val() not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, debugging, pug

I am having issues using jquery to set the value a element which calls a function. Here is the code

Element:

```
 each outlet in FBoutlets  
        br
        label(for='FBoutlet') Facebook: #{outlet.FBoutlets.name}  
        input(type='checkbox', value='', onchange="streamFB(" + outlet.FBoutlets.FBpageId + "," + JSON.stringify(outlet.FBoutlets.FBaccessToken) + ")", name='FBoutletCredentials', id='FBoutlet')
```

Function:

```
  script.
    window.fbAsyncInit  = function()  {
    FB.init({
      appId             : '20212222222',
      autoLogAppEvents  : true,
      xfbml             : true,
      version           : 'v2.12'
      });
      };

    function streamFB(pageId, accessToken){
      FB.api(
        '/' + pageId + '/live_videos',
        'POST',
        {access_token: accessToken},
        function(response) {
            let rtmp = response.stream_url
            console.log(rtmp)
            console.log(response)
            $(this).val() = rtmp;
        }
      );
    }
```

$(this).val() is returning undefined, I need to use this because the element id dynamically generated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

jquery val function takes argument value as assigning value

## Definition and Usage

> The val() method returns or sets the value attribute of the selected
>   elements.

## When used to return value:

This method returns the value of the value attribute of the FIRST matched element.

## When used to set value:

This method sets the value of the value attribute for ALL matched elements.

Note: The val() method is mostly used with HTML form elements.

## Syntax

Return the value attribute:

```
$(selector).val()
```

Set the value attribute:

```
$(selector).val(value)
```

Set the value attribute using a function:

```
$(selector).val(function(index,currentvalue));
```

## Parameter   Description

> value Required. Specifies the value of the value attribute
>   function(index,currentvalue)  Optional. Specifies a function that
>   returns the value to set. index - Returns the index position of the
>   element in the set currentvalue - Returns the current value attribute
>   of selected elements

source:https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/html_val.asphttps://www.w3schools.com/jquery/html_val.asp

Answer (score 7):

You should change it

```
$(this).val() = rtmp;
```

to

```
$(this).val(rtmp);
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you have to update **$(this).val() = rtmp;** to -

```
$(this).val(rtmp);
```

Or,

```
this.value = rtmp;
```

Answer (score 1):

Change `$(this).val() = rtmp;`
to `$(this).val(rtmp);`

Answer (score 0):

Alternate solutions,

```
$(this)[0].value = rtmp;
```

or

```
this.value = rtmp;
```